# Reactive function in svelte not firing when the value changes?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

Entire code sample below.

The problem I have is that I know vatSuccess is actually changing successfully. However when I try to do anything with it in a reactive manner when I know it should be true it does not seem to work.

In the sample below I would expect the reactive statement console logging 'vatSuccess' to run twice first when it's declared as false and then again when it becomes true.

However it only runs the first time

```
let vatSuccess = false
let nameSuccess = false

function handleVatValidation(): Error {
    // Vat is optional so putting nothing passes validation
    if (companyInformation.vat.length === 0) {
        vatSuccess = true
        vatError = null
        return null
    }

    if (companyInformation.vat.length < 6) {
        vatSuccess = false
        vatError = 'vat must be at least 6 characters'
        return 'vat must be at least 6 characters'
    }

    vatSuccess = true
    console.log('vatSuccess', vatSuccess) // This code runs and prints true

    vatError = null
    return null
}

$: {
    console.log('vatSuccess', vatSuccess) // This only runs once when it is false
}
```

I have tried to change it liek this so vatSuccess is a reactive value to begin with but the behaviour is the same.

```
$: vatSuccess = false
```

Answer (score 1):

Functions do not call themselves and any variable being read inside the function has no bearing on reactivity.

If the function is called in the template (HTML part of a component) or a reactive block (`$: ...`), it will be re-evaluated if the function itself changes or one of the arguments.

This function has a dependency on `companyInformation` but this is not "visible". Either turn that into an argument or declare the entire function itself reactively:

```js
$: handleVatValidation = () => {
   ...
}
```

(`$: vatSuccess = false` does nothing because it contains no additional dependencies that would cause a re-evaluation.)